# How to get attribute from JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I currently have this JSON response for `$e->getResponseBody()` and I was wondering how do I `json_decode` the `detail` attribute response so it will only echo that string on page?

```
object(stdClass)#20 (1){  
   [  
      "errors"
   ]   => array(1)   {  
      [  
         0
      ]      => object(stdClass)#21 (3)      {  
         [  
            "category"
         ]         => string(20) "PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR"         [  
            "code"
         ]         => string(13) "CARD_DECLINED"         [  
            "detail"
         ]         => string(14) "Card declined."
      }
   }
}
```

I currently have this but doesn't seem to output anything:

```
$json = file_get_contents($e->getResponseBody());
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->detail;
```

Comment: Add `true` as the 2nd parameter to `json_decode()` so you get an array instead of an object. `$obj = json_decode($json,true);`

Comment: @MrGlass Why?  That doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: `echo $obj->errors[0]->detail;` ... er... I hate looking at objects with `var_dump` ...

Comment: @devon, It makes accessing it very straight forward for someone not familiar with objects.

Comment: @MrGlass Well, it changes `->errors[0]->details` to `['errors'][0]['details']`, but I don't see any need for the OP to have an array here instead of an object especially because we don't know how they are using this object later on and we don't want to affect the rest of their code to solve a simple problem.

Comment: @devon, his question was specifically how to get 'detail', and he clearly didn't know how to do that with object syntax. So I suggested he get an array, which hopefully he understands how to use. I can't guess what else he may be doing with that stdObject.

Comment: @MrGlass That's my whole point.  You make an assumption about arrays but the OP never says anything about arrays.  Your comment could lead them to believe that having an object is a problem, but it's not..

Comment: @Devon, we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: When I do `$json = file_get_contents($e->getResponseBody());
   $obj = json_decode($json, true);
   echo $obj->errors[0]->detail;` I get nothing displaying however when I just var dump `$e->getResponseBody()` I get the whole object

Comment: I don't mind having an object or array. I just need something that works in this situation.

Comment: `$json = file_get_contents($e->getResponseBody());
   $obj = json_decode($json, true);
   var_dump($obj['errors'][0]['details']);` This also gives me 'NULL'

Comment: @ZacRam if getResponseBody() is already an object, don't run json_decode on it..

Answer (score 0):

You have an object that contains an array named errors which at the 0 index contains an object.  So `$obj->errors[0]` is the object you want, and you want to get the detail property of that object.

```
object array index property
 |       |   |     |
$obj->errors[0]->detail
```